# "mount: special device /dev/sdc1 doesn't exist" but according to fdisk -l, it does

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, fdisk, xfs

I'm booted into a live usb linux environment, and I plugged in a hard drive. It's listed in fdisk -l as /dev/sdc{,1}, is a 3tb drive, and has a single partition containing an xfs filesystem.

But when i try to mount it with

```
sudo bash
mkdir /3
mount /dev/sdc1 /3
```

I get:

```
 "mount: special device /dev/sdc1 doesn't exist"
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/sdc*` show?

Comment: Can we also get the output of `fdisk -l`?

Comment: The output of `stat /dev/sdc1` and `blkid /dev/sdc1` would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

A 3TB disk cannot have a MBR, because it exceeds the (in-)famous 2TiB limit. It sports instead a GPT, GUID Partition Table. As such, it cannot be inspected and/or handled by utilities of the fdisk family, it must be operated on by gdisk and similar (cgdisk, sgdisk). Also, the live  distro you mention but do not specify must have in-built support for EFI-GPT. I suggest you take a look at [this excellent introduction article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gpt/index.html), by the very same guy who wrote gdisk.

Answer (score -3):

Really its an good question, We can mount the third part/temporary hard drive on any customized folder at our Operating system

But it wouldn't be mount on permanent basis, Because there is lot of issue to know the UUID for temporary hard drive to make its entry in /etc/fstab file